# Using graphql` in Relay.createContainer

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have a specific use case where I want to use new graphql`babel transform since it provides graphql query name lookup but without createFragmentContainer. Is there any way to write a converter from gaphql` to Relay.QL`?

I looked at the output of both Relay.QL`and graphql` but couldn't figure out a good way to convert graphql`to Relay.QL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out here is the sample of code I have written

`const convertToClassicQuery = query => query.classic(RelayQL_GENERATED).node;`

Here is small library to transform the createContainer to accept relay  modern queries

```
import Relay from 'react-relay/classic';

const RelayQL_GENERATED = require('react-relay/classic').QL; // eslint-disable-line

const convertToClassicQuery = query => query.classic(RelayQL_GENERATED).node;

const convertFragments = fragments => _.mapValues(fragments, fragment => () => convertToClassicQuery(fragment()));

const convertFragmentProps = (fragmentProps) => {
  fragmentProps.fragments = convertFragments(fragmentProps.fragments); // eslint-disable-line
  return fragmentProps;
};
const createContainer = (Component, fragmentProps) => Relay.createContainer(Component, convertFragmentProps(fragmentProps));


module.exports = {
  createContainer,
};
```